# ExtJS 4 - Control events of items in MVC

Tags: extjs4, menuitem, extjs-mvc

I have an application in MVC with a view class:

```
Ext.define('a.view.Mainmenu' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.menu.Menu',
    alias: 'widget.mainmenu',
    text: 'Menu',
    items: [
    {
        xtype: 'menucheckitem',
        id: 'mci1',
        text: 'a'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'menucheckitem',
        id: 'mci2',
        text: 'b'
    }]
});
```

How I can control the click events of the menucheckitems in the controller? I want to check if the menucheckitems are checked.
I tried something in the init function of the controller, but there is an error (item.down("mci1") is null):

```
...
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'mainmenu': {
            click: function(item) {
                if (item.down('mci1').checked == true) {
                    ...
                }
                if (item.down('mci2').checked == true) {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

How I could do it right?

Answer (score 1):

@Ringo,

Neither the menuitem or menucheckitem have a method of down() available to them according to the Sencha docs (http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.menu.CheckItem-event-checkchange).

So, that is why those aren't working.

There is an event for the xtype of menucheckitem called 'checkchange'. This event makes the following arguments available for your function:

- this (Ext.menu.CheckItem) <= the actual menucheckitem that was checked/unchecked (so mci1 or mci2 depending on which the user clicked on)
- checked (Boolean) <= true if the change set the menucheckitem as checked and false if unchecked.

So, this would only require you to do something like:

```
...
init: function() {
this.control({
    'mainmenu menucheckitem': {
        checkchange: function(item, checked) {
            if (checked) {
                if(item.id == 'mci1'){
                  ...
                }
            }else{
                ...
            }
        }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The item parameter is already your menu item. You don't have to query down.

so it would be:

```
if(item.checked && item.getId() == 'mci1'){
...
}
```